# Nav-bar drop-down drops down then collapses immediately

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It is a flask app. I got the theme from [here](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/).

It is asking for more details and I am unsure what I can provide. It is pretty simple. The drop down just drops down for a sec then collapses. I have posted the relevant code. Is it something with the order of the links to the CSS or JS?

Here is the main layout file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>David McLaughlin</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.0.0-beta.2/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/flatly.css') }}" media="screen"> -->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani|Karla|Michroma" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="container">
                {% block body %}

                {% endblock %}
                {% include 'includes/_messages.html' %}
            <hr>
                <footer class="footer text-center">
                    <div>
                        <span>@ David McLaughlin, 2017</span>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
            <br>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('editor')</script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```